# Всегда рисуется вся клиенсткая область. Это нормально?

Tags: winapi

Графика в окне мигает. Хотел получить координаты обновляемого прямоугольника, потом в тексте попадания вычислить диапазоны циклов и перерисовать только обновляемую часть окна. Раздебажил, а в PaintStructure.rcPaint всегда вся клиенсткая область. Даже если я не вызываю инвалидейт рект на всё окно, а меняю размеры окна, всё равно в PaintStructure.rcPaint вся клиентская область. Это нормально? Как рисовать только обновляемое?

Answer (score 1):

Да, это нормально. Обычно окна создаются с классом, стиль которого включает флаги `CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW`, соответственно при изменении размера перерисовывается целиком. Это поведение можно поменять, убрав упомянутые выше флаги и самостоятельно вызывая перерисовку окна после изменения размера.